# How do I get a DataTextField value from another table?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, objectdatasource

I have a dropdownlist populated with a list of locations. The datasource is an ObjectDataSource named `objectDataSourcePlaces`. The DataValueField is `PlaceID`. The DataTextField, the value I want the user to see, resides in another table.

I'm guessing I need to perform some sort of JOIN to get the display string from the second table. The question, how do I get the display string from the second table and use that in my dropdownlist?

Comment: Join these tables in your SQL and add this column to your `location` object.

Comment: Are your problems SQL related(how to join tables) or are they .NET related(how to add a property to a class)?

Comment: @Tim - I'm okay with the SQL stuff and C#. I'm not sure how to do this in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would join the tables on the DataValueField and select the text field.

For example:

```
Select T1.PlaceId, T2.Text as DTField
from Table1 T1
left join Table2 T2 on T1.PlaceID= T2.PlaceId
Where some condition
```

**Additional Info**

I see you're having trouble in ASP.net side. all you'd have to do is set the DataTextField to the text field you selected via the joined tables. In my example above you'd do something like this:

```
   DataTextField = "DTField"
```

You can do this in code on Load or whenever it is needed or in the Markup as an attribute of the drop down. Hope this helps.

Comment: okay, I get the concept of what you're doing. I'm still hung up on how to implement it. How / where do I implement the JOIN expression? In markup, I have my dropdownlist and objectdatasource. Due to the complexity of the BAL, I'd rather not mess with that. I set the SelectMethod property to "SelectPlaces" and created a method in my code behind. Now what?

Comment: you would have to adjust the object data source. You can do that through the design view. Just select the object data source and click configure data source.

Comment: maybe this will help. http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/06/gridview-objectdatasource-insert-update.html